# Get product id in "woocommerce_quantity_input" pluggable function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, pluggable

I am using `woocommerce_quantity_input` **pluggable function** to modify the quantity input from a text box to a dropdown on my site.

On the cart page, when outputting the quantity input, **I need to get the product ID** so I can grab an ACF field from the single product page.

My code:

```php
function woocommerce_quantity_input($data = null, $args = array(), $echo = true) {
    global $product;
    $set_quantity_limit = get_field('set_quantity_limit');
    if ( !$data || is_product() ) {
        $defaults = array(
            'input_id'   => '',
            'input_name'   => 'quantity',
            'input_value'   => '1',
            'max_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
            'min_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
            'step'         => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
        );
    } else {
        $defaults = array(
            'input_id'   => $data['input_id'],
            'input_name'   => $data['input_name'],
            'input_value'   => $data['input_value'],
            'step'         => apply_filters( 'cw_woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
            'max_value'     => apply_filters( 'cw_woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
            'min_value'     => apply_filters( 'cw_woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
        );
    }

    if($set_quantity_limit){
        if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
            $min = $defaults['min_value'] = 1;
            $max = $defaults['max_value'] = $set_quantity_limit;
            $step = $defaults['step'] = 1;
        }
    } else {
        if ( ! empty( $defaults['min_value'] ) )
            $min = $defaults['min_value'];
        else $min = 1;
    
        if ( ! empty( $defaults['max_value'] ) )
            $max = $defaults['max_value'];
        else $max = 6;
    
        if ( ! empty( $defaults['step'] ) )
            $step = $defaults['step'];
        else $step = 1;
        
    }
    
    $options = '';
    for ( $count = $min; $count <= $max; $count = $count+$step ) {
        $selected = (($count == $defaults['input_value']) ? ' selected' : '');
        $suffix_text_with_count = $count . ( ( $count == 6 ) ? ' - 1 Mastercase' : ' box - 12 ct.' );
        $options .= '<option value="' . $count . '"'.$selected.'>' . ( ( $set_quantity_limit ) ? $count : $suffix_text_with_count ) . '</option>';
    }
    $string = '<div class="quantity quantity_select" style="' . $defaults['style'] . '">';
        $string .= '<label class="screen-reader-text" for="' . esc_attr( $defaults['input_id'] ) . '">' . _x( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ) . '</label>';
        $string .= '<select ';
        $string .= 'name="' . esc_attr( $defaults['input_name'] ) . '" ';
        $string .= 'title="' . _x( 'Qty', 'Product Description', 'woocommerce' ) . '" ';
        $string .= 'class="qty">';
            $string .= $options;
        $string .= '</select>';
    $string .= '</div>';
    
    if ( $echo ) {
        echo $string;
    } else {
        return $string;
    }
}
```

This function applies the changes to all quantity inputs, not just those on the shop page, the single product page and the cart page.

Answer (score 1):

Product is passed as as 2nd argument to the `woocommerce_quantity_input` function.

So use it like this:

```php
function woocommerce_quantity_input( $args = array(), $product = null, $echo = true ) {
    if ( is_null( $product ) ) {
        $product = $GLOBALS['product'];
    }

    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {

        $product_id = $product->get_id();
    
        echo 'Product ID = ' . $product_id;
        // etc..
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I will test this out and post an update.

Comment: While this works perfectly fine on the shop page and the single product page, it crashes on the Cart page: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on null which is $product_id = $product->get_id();

Comment: This doesn't work for me either but it's because  I have $data = null as a n argument and you have $product = null as an argument. I've posted the full code. Thanks.

Comment: @junky I didn't downvote your question. But it would make a difference if you posted a clear question right away versus having to edit it afterwards. That has nothing to do with being an expert